# GE THQL1120GF Equivalent replacement breaker

Tags: circuit-breaker

I have a hot tub served by an outside panel with a 220 volt gfi breaker and a 120 v 20 amp gfi breaker.  The 20 amp breaker has tripped a couple of times and I've noticed that the TEST function button on it no longer works.  I'd like to replace that breaker, A GE THQL1120GF breaker.  Although I have found a few places that sells that breaker in new condition it seems it has been discontinued by GE. I also see that I could get a GE THQL1120GFTP from ACE hardware or Menards (a Wisconsin big box building material store) or a GE THQL1120GFT from several online sources.

Can I substitute the THQL1120GFTP or the THQL1120GFT for the THQL1120GF?  are they electrically and mechanically equivalent?  Which might be the better replacement?

Or is there some other brand breaker (Siemans) that's equivalent to the THQL1120GF?

Comment: *You can’t do a meaningful test with wires still attached*. The GFCI needs its own neutral pigtail, but all other wires must be removed.  It should now reset. Test it again.

Comment: When you say that the "TEST" button no longer works, does the TEST button no longer trip the breaker?  Also, what make/model is the hot tub disconnect box itself?

Comment: @threephaseeel when the test button is pushed the breaker does not trip; nothing happens.  The 220 volt GE breaker test button does trip the breaker.  The box has a GE label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### You're looking at the right thing, either way

The THQL1120GF was replaced with the THQL1120GFT when the UL 943 mandate for automatic self-testing in GFCIs went in; the P suffix is likely simply for blister (retail) packaging vs a breaker sold loose, as you'd get at an electrical supply house.

Comment: Just a quick followup.  Firstly replacing the breaker seems to have fixed the problem.  It's been over a week and no trips.  Previously trips had been happening every few days with no apparent cause.  Test button now works on new breaker.  Instructions that came with GE THQL1120GFT breaker say nothing about removing loads for periodic tests.

Comment: @MikeD -- yeah, you don't need to remove loads from a GFCI for self-testing